# How is the dialogue different from the original when beating a Koopa Kid while wearing a Frog Suit?

Tags: super-mario-bros-3

According to [this website](https://themushroomkingdom.net/codes/smb3), in the section labeled "I'll trade you for that wand..." you get different dialogue from the king if you beat a Koopa Kid while wearing a Frog, Hammer, or Tanooki suit. What is this dialogue, and how it it different from the original text?
Note: I haven't played Super Mario Bros. 3 before, 
and so I don't know what the king's dialogue normally is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The original text, if you beat the Koopa Kid with no suit on, says:

> "Oh splendid, splendid! I am back to my old self again. Thank you so much. Here is a letter from the princess."

From [this video.](https://youtu.be/EOeArnm7yRI?t=1672)

---

[Frog Suit](https://www.mariowiki.com/Frog_Suit):

> If Mario or Luigi defeats a Koopaling while in Frog form, the restored king will say, "Oh me, oh my! You've been transformed! Shall I change you back with this wand?"

Also, [here is a video of the special dialogue occurring with the frog suit.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MIoU4-mt8w)

---

[Tanooki Suit:](https://www.mariowiki.com/Tanooki_Suit)

> In Super Mario Bros. 3, if Mario or Luigi defeats a Koopaling while wearing a Tanooki Suit, the restored king will say, "Thank you, kind raccoon. Please tell me your name."

Also, [here is a video of the special dialogue occurring with the Tanooki suit.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zagh11aX7_k)

---

[Hammer suit:](https://www.mariowiki.com/Hammer_Suit)

> “Hey you! How about lending me your clothes? No dice!? What a drag!” —Kings, Super Mario Bros. 3

Also, [here is a video of the special dialogue occurring when Mario is wearing a hammer suit.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpA2FnQosx4)

Comment: Good find, but this seems to only partially answer the question. The OP also asked how it differs from the original text

Comment: @Wondercricket Haha, missed that because of the title. I added the other dialogue for the other two suits.